# Use an msword document as template using google script

Tags: javascript, docx

I'm trying to create a script that takes a template page (created in doc or docx), then replace some keywords and finally create a document with several pages (each page is like the template). All this using google script.

I created a template page and I put this in my google Drive account.

for example, if I put a line for open the template:

```
var doc_template = DriveApp.getFileById(SOME_ID_TO_A_DOC_FILE);
```

I get the document, but I cannot replace the tokens (for instance FIELD1, FIELD2) there're inside the document. Please I need help in this. thanks!

Comment: doc and docx are pretty different. on docx though, have you seen this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307163/manipulating-microsoft-word-office-2007-docx-document-from-php

Comment: please consider adding more details to the question. What have you tried ? What are the problems you encountered ?